# GPS NEO 6M V2 Raspberry pi 4 data missing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gps, grafana, influxdb

I am using gps neo 6m v2 and a raspberry pi to monitor vehicle health. I have also use obd to get the data of engine sensors, in this case I was facing problem on the gps which is data from the gps is missing for few minutes. If I started the travel and from one place to another, from the beginning until sometime I getting data and suddenly data is missing and return back normal. In the between data missing is the biggest issue for me. I could not find the solution why the data missing in the middle of the way i travel along. please give me a solution.

the python code used for get the GPS data from raspberry pi to influxdb and visualize in Grafana server.

```
from datetime import datetime
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point, WritePrecision
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS
import serial

# Setup database
token = "<mytoken>"
org = "<myorg>"
bucket = "<mybucket>"

with InfluxDBClient(url="<influxurl>", token=token, org=org) as client:
    write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)
    # Setup dataload
    json_dataload = []

    ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0")
    gpgga_info = "$GPGGA,"

    GPGGA_buffer = 0
    NMEA_buff = 0


    def convert_to_degrees(raw_value):
        decimal_value = raw_value / 100.00
        degrees = int(decimal_value)
        mm_mmmm = (decimal_value - int(decimal_value)) / 0.6
        position = degrees + mm_mmmm
        position = "%.4f" % position
        return position


    while True:
        received_data = str(ser.readline())  # read NMEA string received
        GPGGA_data_available = received_data.find(gpgga_info)  # check for NMEA>
        if (GPGGA_data_available > 0):
            GPGGA_buffer = received_data.split("$GPGGA,", 1)[1]  # store data com>
            NMEA_buff = (GPGGA_buffer.split(','))
            nmea_latitude = []
            nmea_longitude = []

            extract_latitude = NMEA_buff[1]  # extract latitude from >
            extract_longitude = NMEA_buff[3]  # extract longitude from>
            lat = float(extract_latitude)
            lat = convert_to_degrees(lat)
            longi = float(extract_longitude)
            longi = convert_to_degrees(longi)

            point = Point("latest GPS") \
            .field("latitude", lat) \
            .field("longitude", longi) \
            .time(datetime.utcnow(), WritePrecision.NS)

            json_dataload.append(point)

            # Send our payload

            write_api.write(bucket, org,json_dataload)
```

Comment: I'd probably dump and create a new token for the bucket, since you've shared it with the whole world. Also, i'm not sure if it's a good idea to leave your influxdb instance at that IP and port going forward. Regarding your problem, it can be a whole buch of things based on the set of information you have provided. Do you have local logs on the PI to rule out the possibility of signal loss while travelling? Device failure midway? Other external causes that's not related to the code here?

Comment: from your first question, i dont save anything in the pi's local file or anywhere in the pi, im just sending data straigh to my influxdb. and for the second question, im using gps neo6m v2 as my gps device so that i dont know how to figure out thw device failure because its blinking all the time. is that any devices you can suggest to be more accurate?